# How to flip Y axis of the texcoord in OpenGL ARB shader?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

It can be displayed normally with the shader below, but the image is upside down.

```
!!ARBfp1.0
TEX result.color, fragment.texcoord, texture[0], RECT;
END
```

So I'am trying to flip the Y-axis of the texcoord, like:

```
!!ARBfp1.0
TEMP uv;
MOV uv, fragment.texcoord;
ADD uv.y, 1.0, -fragment.texcoord.y;
TEX result.color, uv, texture[0], RECT;
END
```

It not work. I am not familiar with OpenGL ARB assembly language.

I found the reference of the TEX instruction [here](http://www.downloads.redway3d.com/downloads/public/documentation/bk_bm_custom_custom_gpu_arb.html#i7379), it says

> Takes the first three components of the source vector to sample from the specified texture target on the specified texture image unit.

I doubt that fragment.texcoord is the same as texcoord in GLSL, where sampling coordinates only use two components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `RECT` as texture target (as opposed to e.g. `2D`), so your Y texture coordinate do *not* range from [0.0..1.0), but from [0.0..texture height).
So, your computation of `ADD uv.y, 1.0, -fragment.texcoord.y` is wrong.

Comment: My texture height is 1080, I change 1.0 to 1080, it's OK. Thanks.